# Using Text To Speech in Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, text-to-speech

I am trying to use the TTS plugin in Cordova, but I cannot get it to work.  I am new to Cordova so I feel like I am doing something obviously wrong but I cannot figure it out.  I have the following code

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
  navigator.tts.speak('Welcome to my awesome app');
  function alertDismissed() {
// do something
  }

  navigator.notification.alert(
      'You are the winner!',  // message
      alertDismissed,         // callback
      'Game Over',            // title
      'Done'                  // buttonName
  );

}, false);
```

If I comment out line 2, then everything works fine and I get the alert, but if I leave it uncommented, then nothing works.  I have checked to make sure it is in the plugins json and it appears when I list the plugins through the Cordova CLI.  I have tried a bunch of example code too for the TTS plugin which has not worked either.  This leads me to beleive I am not loading it correctly or something, but again I cannot figure out what.